# How to paginate over Stripe API results?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I want to find a way to paginate over Stripe API results past a certain number.  The issue is, as time goes on and more API documentation appears, a page will be loaded with way too much data.  Preferably I would like to have a months worth of data per page.

**Question:** How can I limit to results on the views side and create pagination for it.

For example, I have this in my controller:

```
  @payouts = Stripe::Payout.list(
      {
        limit: 100,
        expand: ['data.destination']
      },
      { stripe_account: current_user.stripe_token } 
    )
```

Views:

```
 #table html stuffs
    ...
    <% @payouts.each do |payout| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(as_table_row_payout(payout["amount"] / 100.00 )) %></td>
            <td><%= as_table_row_payout(Time.at(payout["arrival_date"]).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) %></td>

        </tr>
  <% end %>
    ...
```

I have the will_paginate gem but that didn't seem to work.  So I figured there may be a way with jquery / JS to solve this.  Does anyone have a solution to limit the amount of API JSON data that is requested on the view page?

Somewhat of an update and a bit off topic... (sorry if this strays from the post itself and starts a new conversation)
I have found a gem for will_paginate to paginate through API requests

I have found the api-pagination gem here: https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination

Although, when i installed the gem and followed the directions, nothing seemed to happen - I manually created an api_pagination.rb config file and did what it seems like the docs say to do as well... Anyone use this before?

Comment: What is class of `@payouts`  ?

Comment: Its under def account in my dashboard controller.

Comment: no, check the class of payouts with `  @payouts.class` what are you getting ?

Comment: Oh! I get " Stripe::ListObject " --- is that what you were looking for?  thats from doing "<%= @payouts.class %>" in the view

Comment: Did you check `kaminari gem` ?

Comment: ill take a look into but from the github i believe it does what the will_paginate gem already does.  I think the api-pagination gem is the gem way to go but theres probably a way to do this through jquey/JS -  Although it looks like kaminari can do arrays which could help.  thanks, ill take a look

Comment: Yes. Kaminari gem has lots of scopes, you can use it as you want.

Answer (score 2):

The Stripe API uses cursors for pagination rather than just specifying a page and a page size (which is what will_paginate and kaminari do).

If you look at the api docs for [listing payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/list) the arguments you'll need to use are `ending_before` and `starting_after`.

If you retrieve 10 payouts with ids `[1, 2, ..., 10]` and you want the next "page" of results you'll need to make the request again with `starting_after=10`. I.e. from the payout with id=10 get me the next 10 payouts.

I'm not aware of any gem support for this (although that definitely doesn't mean that there isn't any!) and I've tended to roll my own by generating "Next" and "Previous" links to set `starting_after` the id of the last payout in my current page or `ending_before` the id of the first payout in my current page. E.g.

```
<%= link_to 'Previous', list_payouts_url(first_payout_id: @payouts.first.id) %>
<%= link_to 'Next', list_payouts_url(last_payout_id: @payouts.last.id) %>
```

and then setting the `ending_before` or `starting_after` to `params[:first_payout_id]` and `params[:last_payout_id]`.

Comment: To clarify, I will need to set up params to save this stripe data? I did notice stripe has auto pagination but i can't see how it relates to the front end view.  I know it can be done but i haven't sorted it out and all tutorials ive found on it are aimed towards more console style to retrieve in "pages"

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add parameters to your `Stripe::Payout.list` call and the value of those parameters will be dependent on the payouts you've already fetched.